# Smartform - Horizontal line trough barcode

Tags: barcode, abap, sap-smart-forms

I already have made a new font to create the barcode in my Smartform. But now the next step.

How can I create a barcode with a horizontal line trough it?

Example:
[image: Barcode with horizontal line]

Hope anyone could help me. I'm pretty stuck here.

Comment: Just curious - why do you need this?

Comment: When an article is no longer available, employees have to know they can't order it anymore ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't think there is a strikethrough option for the fonts.
if the barcode is always present at the same place, and nearly occupy the same place, you could use one of the following method

- simulate the line with an empty windows over the one containing the barcode, with a non null border
- use an empty window with an image containing the line

regards

Comment: Thanks PATRY. It's not the most beautifull option but it works :)